# Adding TIME to TIME

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to add two TIME variables.

```
DECLARE @time1 TIME
DECLARE @time2 TIME
DECLARE @outt TIME
SET @time1 = '00:00:01'
SET @time2 = '03:00:21'
SET @outt = @time1 + @time2
```

When I try to do this I got error like:

> 'Operand data type time is invalid for add operator.'

Comment: You understand that it's literally nonsense to add 2:00 pm to 3:00 pm, right? The "time" data type *"defines a time of a day. The time is without time zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock."* [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx). That's why you got the error. Standard SQL has an interval data type; SQL Server does not. That's why you need to use Dateadd() in SQL Server. See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use `DATEADD`. Here is how you add the one second.

```
DATEADD(ss,@time2,1)
```

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Or....

```
DECLARE @time1 TIME
DECLARE @time2 TIME
DECLARE @outt TIME
SET @time1 = '00:00:04'
SET @time2 = '03:00:21'

declare @s int = (select (datepart(hh,@time1) * 60 * 60) + (datepart(mi,@time1) * 60) + datepart(ss,@time1))
select @s

select dateadd(ss,@s,@time2)
```

Comment: Its not about just adding second, @time1 can have different value.

Comment: see the edit @mq007 i had a mistake in the code that wouldn't scale. This should though.